# which server model should I use for it? SQlite or MySql ?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am a little bit new to Android. I need to do some kind of a reservation system. In this system, there will be 2 different users. First one, making the reservation and second one create reservation.

So I need one applications and 2 different interface. Second one will create reservation and first one will make the reservation, and this server system will provide communication with this two users action. **So which server system should I use for it? SQlite or MySql ?**

Finally; sorry for English mistakes:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope i get you right.
if you going to use on same device use local sq-lite with content provider the allow you communicate between applications

if you want to use in different devices you need remote server with sql/mySQl and web services to retain data from server. also you can use this [Parse.com](https://parse.com/products/core)

Comment: Yes this application make communicate at diffrent deveices

Comment: ok then use second approach or create by your self sql/mySql database and webservice to get/store your data in dataBase via web Services,o r use parse.com or similar api's that provide store data in cloud and take care of creation webservices and data base.

Comment: Thank you, will try parse.com first